# PHP AJAX duplicating cookies in certain directories

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

I have the following file-folder structure:

public_html >> index.php, post.php, etc.

public_html >> include >> common.php, security.php, ajaxfile.php, etc.

public_html >> ajaxlibs >> chk_login.php, etc.

The following file has many functions including one for logging in, and the file is called almost everywhere:

security.php:

```
 <?php

//checking user credentials goes here ......
//...........

    function logIn($newToken,$uID)
    {
            $cookieExpiry= time()+36000;
            //set user login (ul) cookie:
            setcookie('token',$newToken,$cookieExpiry,'/','',FALSE,true);
            setcookie('uid',$uID,$cookieExpiry,'/','',FALSE,true);
            return 'success';
    }
    //if user credentials are valid:
    logIn('token_hashed_via_another_func', $uID);
?>
```

The cookie is set perfectly on logging in like this:

> Cookie name: token, value: 'token_hashed_via_another_func', path: '/'

But when I call an AJAX file that is on the same directory as security.php, such as include/ajaxfile.php, I get a new cookie with a different value and path as follows:

> Cookie name: token, value: 'different_value_with_unkown_hashing_resource', path: '/include/'

So, I get a new cookie with the same name but different value and path, and the original cookie is not removed.

Surprisingly, if I move the same AJAX file to another folder than the folder that has security.php, I don't get the same problem.

I'm almost sure it has to do with AJAX to some extent, because when I require files from the same directory (i.e. include), the problem doesn't occur.

Here's an example of how I'm calling the AJAX file:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "include/ajaxfile.php",
      dataType: "text",
      async: true,
      cache: false,
      timeout: 40000,
      success: function(response)
      {
          //do something or even nothing
      },
      error: function()
      {
         alert("error!");
      }
    });
```

Comment: The problem seems to be occurring randomly. So far I can't tell what the reason is. I always do the same thing. However, sometimes the cookies get removed and sometimes they don't.

Comment: Now I'm facing the same issue, but only one folder so far. The other folders are not causing this problem. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of attempts, it turns out that the problem had to do with the browser cache.
I'm using Chrome, and after removing ALL the cache and cookies stored, the issue does not occur any more-- so far at least.
Thank God!